# java util classes

Tags: java

Util class in java can be made in two ways

```
class Utils  
{   
  public static ReturnType someUtilMethod(  
 // ...   
}
```

and execute util method by

```
Utils.someUtilMethod(...);
```

Or I can make

```
class Utils  
{  
  public Utils(){}     
  public ReturnType someUtilMethod(  
 // ...   
}
```

and execute util method by

```
new Utils().someUtilMethod(...)
```

What way is better? Are some differences between this ways?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally Util class contains Utility methods which doesn't need to store the state of Object to process and so `static` methods are good fit there

Comment: +1 I would use `public enum Utils {; ` to show the class has no instances.

Comment: Totally agree - there is absolutely no reason to make utility method `non-static`. Besides that, less time & memory is spent on utility method invocation in case of `static` method.

Answer (score 2):

A utility function should always be `static`, unless for some reason it depends on the *state* of some other variables, and those variables need to be remembered between calls.

The latter should almost never happen, although something like a pseudo-random number generator might be a good case.

The `Math` functions are a good example of utility functions.  When you call `Math.sin()` the result depends *only* on the supplied parameter.  There is no "state" involved, so there's no need to create an object.

Answer (score 1):

**static access** will be a better approach as in Util class hold methods which are not concerned with the attributes of the Objects.

Another example will be of **Math Class**.

- Math class has **no Instance variables**.
- And has **private constructor**, so no object can be created.
- So in Math class case using static access like Math.PI is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a class that only has static methods, you will not need to instantiate the object everytime you need to use it, saving a line of code and some memory. Just remember to make the default constructor private, so that no one cane inadvertently instantiate it!

Answer (score 0):

A utility class is just a place where to syntactically hold global functions in Java.

Your second example is not covered by the term "utility class". The definition of that concept includes non-instantiability of the class.

The reason to have instance methods would be dynamic method dispatch (to achieve polymorphism), or possibly hold some non-global state. But, as I said, then you would be out of the scope of the term "utility class".